# SearchBuilder DataTables error with displaying date field in default condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, datatables-1.10

When I select default column in conditions datatable `'startdate'` and select condition `'after'` or `'before'` or any other, I get error in browser console:
`TypeError: resolved.replace is not a function`

Although a calendar with date selection should be displayed.
[in this example everything works without errors](https://datatables.net/extensions/searchbuilder/examples/customisation/defaultCondition.html)

Please tell me what the problem is and how to fix it.

I googled the error, tried to fix it using the following links, but it didn’t work:

1. https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/51791/uncaught-typeerror-this-replace-is-not-a-function
2. https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/1586/datatable-is-not-a-function

Perhaps the problem is in ajax, or that the request is executed before the searchBuilder fields themselves are loaded.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.